# Javascript file doesn't load

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I have a mysterious problem - the script file isn't loaded. The same code works on a test server. But when we uploaded it to the live server and looking at the browser console  at "sources", it didn't show up at first. But for a while it did show up , but now it doesn't.

I enqueue the js-file in functions.php:

```
if( is_page_template( 'page-anmalan-adelsmote.php' ) || is_page_template( 'page-anmalan-slutmote.php' ) ){
        wp_register_script('form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/form.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('form');  

    }
```

**Edit**: I have put this code in the  `load_header_scripts()`.
And it is hooked like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_header_scripts');
```

**Edit2** It works if I remove the "if" condition , and just put it in the load header scripts-function:

```
wp_register_script('form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/form.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0');
wp_enqueue_script('form');
```

So, what's wrong with the if condition? (it works in the test version as I said).

The file is of course in the "js"-folder right under the theme folder.
The page in question has a template loaded in frontend which is the `"page-anmalan-slutmote.php"` template.

And the js-file is called `"form.js"`.

There are some issues with "mixed content" where http is mixed with https-content, but in this case I don't think it should have anything to do with it. There are no console errors except "mixed content" and some error with a slider (not related). Do you have any suggestions as to what the problem may be?

Comment: Why are you saying that the stylesheet doesn't load in the title but are talking about loading a javascript file in the question body?

Comment: It's a script file, I was confused..

Comment: What doesn't "not loading" mean? The `script` tag doesn't appear in the source of the page? The URL is incorrect? The script doesn't work? What?

Comment: I mean that a correctly included file is "loaded" by the browser, so it is  loaded (accessible, available, included). This can be tested by placing an "alert()" in a document ready function inside the js-file - which I have, but it isn't executed because the file isn't loaded. What term would you use instead of "loaded"? (edit: I edit the message so it becomes clearer that it is a js-file, not just a script tag)

Comment: `load_header_scripts()` is not a function from WordPress, so we can not know what it does or when it is executed. Can you verify if it is executed on [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action.

Comment: Yes, I forgot - it is hooked to an add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' ..

Comment: If the `if` conditional is the cause of the problem, you need to check that the page you are loading is using one of the page templates checked in the `if` conditional. Why that breaks when you transfer the site from test server to live server........who knows; a deeper look to your site and the migration process is needed to find the reason.

Comment: @Galivan If I've understood you correctly, the `<script>` tag for `form.js` appears correctly even with the `if` conditional, however does not seem to execute. If the slider's JS is loaded and/or executed prior to `form.js`, it's possible that the errors produced by the slider are terminating script execution, thus preventing code in `form.js` from running even though it is in fact loaded. With the `if` conditional back in place, what happens if you place a call to `alert()` at the top of `form.js` rather than inside jQuery's document ready function?